# Is it possible to use the new v41.0 lightning:outputField in huge numbers inside tables? Is it possible to extend it?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, lightning-inputfield, lightning-outputfield, lightning-recordviewform

Today I'm giving the new v41.0 `<lightning:outputField>` a try. I want to use it massively inside an `<aura:iteration>` to build a data-table and want to accomplish the following:

- Internationalized output: correct decimal delimiter, correct date and number formats. Tried `lightning:formattedNumber` does not work as expected, because it takes the settings of the browser, but I need to use the the users salesforce locale not the locale defined in the browser). Basically this is done very good by `<lightning:outputField>`. Exactly as expected!
- **Eventually** I want an editable table with picklists, transaltions, lookups all the good stuff, you name it. And high numbers of it. So I would like to switch to `<lightning:inputField>` in the end. But as starter Read-Only is good enough.

I would need to adjust several things of `<lightning:outputField>`. The mode `variant="label-hidden"` helps but is still messing things up in my layout. Therefore I thought about to extend and customize the component as described here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html

**1. Is it possible at all?**

I have tried this:

```
<aura:component extends="lightning:outputField">
    <!--...-->
</aura:component>
```

But when I want to save the markup, I get only

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
>
> cannot extend non-extensible component

**2. Are Standard Components extensible at all?**

Are **some** / **all** or **none** of the Salesforce-Standard components (those of the namespaces `force:`, `ui:` and `lightning:`) `extensible="true"` or not? Where (documentation, documentation-app, etc.) can I find if and which component is be extensible or not?

**3. Even if it would be possible, is extension a good idea?**

The rendering of the component is not inline. It creates several `display:block;` and `inline-block;` elements in the DOM. This is messing-up my layout (huge table, lots of lines, lots more of `<lightning:outputField>`). Now is extension a good approach to make something which fits only partly better fit into the requirements? The partly good fit is localization: `<lightning:outputField>` comes in good old Visualforce quality I was used to from `<apex:outputField>`! **Perfect!**

**4. Slow and async rendering**

To use lightning:outputField inside a table and inside an iteration over the `<tr>` I was only able to do it like this

```
<tbody>
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.Opportunities }" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!item.Id}" objectApiName="Opportunity">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="CloseDate" variant="label-hidden" />
                </lightning:recordViewForm>
            </td>
            <!-- !! lots more of outputFields to come ... !! </td>-->
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</tbody>
```

I would have preferred to have only on single `<lightning:recordViewForm>` per `<tr>` but this is messing-up the table layout completely. That's the reason for lots of `<lightning:recordViewForm>` per `<tr>`. It works, but I need massive CSS-hacks to adjust the rendering and it becomes very slow and does not scale good.

**5. Is `<lightning:recordViewForm>` designed to be used in high numbers?**

All this looks and feels like `<lightning:recordViewForm>` is designed to be used only once or at least only in a very small number of occurrences per component or page. I did not see it stated in the docs, but is I my feeling correct that it should be used only a few times and not a couple of hundred times? If so, what is the best practice for such tables?

Comment: As an alternate solution, have you looked at lightning:datatable this looks promising with support to all types of fields if you are ready to spin up your own wrapper object and hook it to the data attribute https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm

Comment: @Rao super interesting! This looks really awsome and for sure I will use it - unfortunately here it probably won't work: I need fine-grain access to the cells (css, colorize, custom-content), I need lookups - AND (now it comes!)  lightning:datatable is using as lightning:formattedNumber the clinentside-browser-locale and NOT the serverside-salesforce-user-locale. I dont understand, we salesforce is coming up with such inconsisten locale-behavior. Also the columsizes are adaptable, but are falling back every page-load...

Comment: @Rao, so as nice as a datatable approach will ever be - as an alternative, we will still need flexible building-blocks of whateverTheHeckNamespace:inputField and :outputField to compose all those shiny editable-tables, tree-tables, accordion-tables, nested-editors and whatever ideas the our clients will come up with. My concern now is, that lightning:inputField - **again** like force:inputField - is not as powerful as apex:inputField was in VF.... in my tests more issues and questions came up - and it looks like i will have to ask more of them here ;-)

Comment: totally agree we are just dealing with whatever is getting thrown at us, for some of my projects i have scratched lightning based approach and adapted third party js  route( cavet being I am having to use salesforce supported version and not the latest version at times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible at all?

No.

> 2. Are Standard Components extensible at all?

No.

> 3. Even if it would be possible, is extension a good idea?

It'd be potentially useful, but we can't.

> 4. Slow and async rendering

You shouldn't be using tables. It's a shame that they actually allow it, because tables are not used anywhere in Lightning *at all*. Everything is meant to be responsive, and tables are not responsive by nature. You didn't say exactly how your layout got messed up, but you should look at the [lightning:layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_layout.htm) element to create a grid that can reflow elegantly with fewer CSS hacks.

> 5. Is `<lightning:recordViewForm>` designed to be used in high numbers?

The documentation doesn't say, but I'd have to guess "probably not." You might consider using force:outputField/force:inputField instead. I've had much better luck using combinations of `lightning:layout` and `lightning:layoutItem`. This give you better control over how things are laid out.

Also, I'd solidly recommend pagination if you're looking at more than ~25 items. Actually, using pagination or infinite scrolling might be a better idea anyways; the data could load progressively so that you can minimize the rendering time.

Comment: all very good - only in terms of table I disagree: there is use of tables in lightning, e.g. on any list-view on any top-level tab. there are also SLDS classes for tables like slds-table, slds-table_bordered and there is the new lightning:datatable hot-shot mentioned by @Rao. So tables are dead - long live the tables ;-) I really need them and used properly, html-tables are powerful beasts. aah, and last but not least: force:outputField/force:inputField ==> IMHO total crap, tried today again: no chance inside aura:iteration (known bug!).

Comment: mess-up by lightning:outputField is DOM-output as display:block; and inline-block; done by Salesforce. I need display:inline because I need to decorate stuff in the same cell by red-yellow-green indicators without having the lightning:outputField taking 100% width (as a result of display:block). I hacked it away by wrapping lightning:outputField and applying CSS selectively. Works fine for now, but is unsafe. Slowness caused by lots of lightning:recordViewForm is crazy but even that I accept for now. Each field pops up after each other, slowly without blocking the UI. looks even nice somehow

Answer (score 0):

What I came eventually up with it a wrapper component around `lightning:recordViewForm` and `lightning:outputField` which looks like that (look at currency and date-formats - they will adapt strictly to the locale of the salesforce-user ignoring any browser or OS locales)

[image]

As you see, the it can be combined with anything in any cell. Full flexibility, rendered inline.

The compo is markup-only, no controller, no helper needed:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="id"                           type="String"                   default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="object"                       type="String"                   default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="field"                        type="String"                   default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="wrap"                         type="Boolean"                  default="true" />
    <style>
        .elfLCXLightningOutputField .elfForceInline *               { display: inline !important; color: inherit; font-size:inherit; }
        .elfLCXLightningOutputField .elfForceWrap *                 { white-space: normal !important; }
    </style>
    <span class="elfLCXLightningOutputField">
        <span class="{! 'elfForceInline ' + (v.wrap?' elfForceWrap ':'') }">
            <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.id}" objectApiName="{!v.object}">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="{!v.field}" variant="label-hidden" />
            </lightning:recordViewForm>
        </span>
    </span>
</aura:component>
```

Used like that

```
<tbody>
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.Opportunities }" var="item">
        <tr class="elfItemRow" 
        >
            <td data-label="" class="elfAlignRight">
                <c:elfLCXLightningOutputField id="{!item.Id}" object="Opportunity" field="CloseDate" />                             
                &nbsp;
                <span class="elfCloseStatusIndicator" title="{! item.___elfCloseStatus }">&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
            <td data-label="" class="elfAlignRight">
                <c:elfLCXLightningOutputField id="{!item.Id}" object="Opportunity" field="CreatedDate" />
            </td>
            <td data-label="" class="elfAlignRight">
                <c:elfLCXLightningOutputField id="{!item.Id}" object="Opportunity" field="Amount" wrap="false"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</tbody>
```

What I notice is that due to the massive use of `lightning:recordViewForm` lots of async request are ongoing. `lightning:recordViewForm` and `lightning:outputField` seem to query their own data. They do not use what I have loaded already in the iterator. The effect is strange but at this stage for me acceptable: it loads the table quickly with all these fields black. Then like an animation each single field pops out asynchronously. It's not blocking the UI.

I expect that this is very inefficient and would love to get a more mass-data-capable inputField from Salesforce - but having the same features like `lightning:outputField`

**Caution:**

Another thing I have noticed is that subsequential settings of the v.Opportunities attribute is causing Javascript exceptions - but ALL the compos do update correctly. As a workaround I wrapped the cmp.set() with a try/catch to suspend the error.